# Does halogenation by phosphorus tribromide lead to an inverted product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

> [image: Question on finding the product of halogenation of an alcohol ((S)‐2‐butanol) with PBr3]

I think it follows the S<sub>N</sub>i mechanism and would not lead to Walden inversion.
Hence, the product should be (*S*)‐2‐bromobutane:

[image: proposed reaction mechanism]

But the answer says otherwise (the problem didn't indicate the presence of pyridine in the reaction mixture though).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the haloalkane product will have the inverse stereochemistry of the alcohol that it was produced form. $\ce{PBr3}$ does this by converting the $\ce{-OH}$ into a good leaving group and providing a nucleophile all in one. This is can be seen in the two step mechanism:

$\hspace{2.4cm}$[image: step 1]

When $\ce{Br-}$ ejects $\ce{PBr2OH}$ in an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction, the stereochemistry is inverted:

$\hspace{3.1cm}$[image: step 2]

Comment: This means it does not follow the SNi mechanism ?

Comment: @AryanJakhar No, it does not. $\ce{SOCl2}$ does, however, if you are looking for something that does retain stereochemistry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, halogenation by $\ce{PBr3}$ will lead to an inverted product, as it follows $\mathrm{S_N2}$ mechanism. In an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ mechanism, the product is formed through inversion as the incoming nucleophile attacks from the side opposite of the leaving group.